# Why does requests.get() not raise when the server can't be found?

Tags: python

In the following code snippet, I know for a fact that `https://asdasdasdasd.vm:8080/v2/api-docs` does not exist. It fails a DNS lookup. Unfortunately, the `get()` never seems to return, raise, or timeout. My logs have only "A" in them. I would expect `A C D` or `A B D`. But I only ever see `A` in the logs.

```
try:
    sys.stderr.write("A")
    resp = requests.get("https://asdasdasdasd.vm:8080/v2/api-docs", timeout=1.0)
    sys.stderr.write("B")
except:
    sys.stderr.write("C")
sys.stderr.write("D")
sys.stderr.flush()
return swag
```

(That URL is not sanitized for this post.  That's actually the URL I'm trying to use while working on this question.)

What am I missing here?

EDIT - I have also tried specifying the timeout as `(1.0,1.0)` but the behavior did not change.

EDIT2 - Per suggestions below, I ran my code from the python and ipython consoles. The code behaves as I expect (`ACD`). Of course, in my real application, I am not running this code from the command line.  I don't know how this matters, but the method containing the code is being invoked by a web service. Specifically, a Swagger endpoint. With my browser, I hit an endpoint that's supposed to return our Swagger documentation. The endpoint (which uses flask_swagger) invokes `init_swagger(...)`. `init_swagger()` calls my method with a Swagger object. That's it. How this matters, I cannot say. It doesn't make any sense to me that something outside of my method should somehow be able to mess with my exception handling.

The only thing I can think of is that Swagger has jacked with the requests class. But now it is dinner time and I am going home.

Comment: throws a ConnectionError when I try it...

Comment: Using requests 2.2.1 (or even 2.7.0) with Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu Trusty, I get "ACD".

Comment: Why do you expect `ABCD` or `ABD`? The correct one should be `ACD` and this is what I got when I run your code.

Comment: You should never see `A B C D`...but you should see `A C D`

Comment: @rnevius good catch, thank you

Comment: @Vader I corrected the 'ABCD' error per rnevius. However, I see nothing but "A".  So it sounds like I have an environmental error perhaps.

Comment: @TonyEnnis What do you see when you execute this `requests.get("https://asdasdasdasd.vm:8080/v2/api-docs", timeout=1.0)` directly in the console?

Comment: @Vader from ipython, instantly: `ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(8, 'nodename nor servname provided, or not known'))` which is of course exactly what I expect.

Comment: That's strange, can you run it in regular console, not in IPython?

Comment: And if you run all of you code in the IPython as well, try to run it from regular console too, maybe IPython handles error earlier than you do.

Answer (score 1):

The following code for me returns `A, C, D`

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError

try:
    print("A")
    resp = requests.get("https://asdasdasdasd.vm:8080/v2/api-docs", timeout=1.0)
    print("B")
except ConnectionError:
    print("C")
print("D")
```

This is because the host cannot be resolved for me, if I swap it out for `localhost`...

```
resp = requests.get("http://localhost/v2/api-docs", timeout=1.0)
```

...then I see an `A`, followed by a period of time before `C` and `D` show.

From reading the comments, I know what is up...
`builtins` has a `ConnectionError` that can be used (without importing anything). Requests doesn't use this exception, instead it uses the one found in `requests.exceptions` if you wish to catch the `ConnectionError` you must catch the correct exception, or it will drop out and not execute the `except` clause.

Comment: I *wish* an exception was being raised. I am getting *nothing* after `A`.

Comment: You need to remove the `try` `except` clause, as you are catching the exception raised in the above example. Copy my code into a new file, run it and edit your post with the output.

Comment: I will do so.  But if I were catching the exception, which is my intent, wouldn't I see `C`?  Or is a ConnectionError not an Exception ??

Comment: If you're not seeing `C`. Your most definitely not importing the `ConnectionError` that requests uses (in my example above) but the one in `builtins` - so use `from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError` at the top of your file, as that is what gets raised.

Comment: The code works from the console. But there's a little more to the story, though it wasn't apparent that it mattered. I will edit the OP.